# How to check email address entered using php?

Tags: php, email

I want to know that is there a way to know that the email id entered by the user is correct or not!

Like if the user enters `email address` shows `Incorrect email entered!` but if the user enters `emailid@gmail.com` shows `Correct email entered!`

Please help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to check whether the email address entered is a syntactically correct email address OR the email address entered is a valid email address registered to a valid domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_match` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)  or `ereg` function and email regular expression

```
//$checkvalue contains your value to be matched

if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $checkvalue)) 
{
    echo "invalid email address";
}
else{
    echo "valid email address";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this thread](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585) for a regex and function with a full explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Use **regular expression** to check if the format of the email provided complies with a standard email format. If you don't know what regular expressions are, do a google search on them, they are a very powerful tool to have for any programmer. Just to get you started check out the **preg_match** method in PHP. Check out this link:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php